# How to pass a vector from a member function to another in the same class?

Tags: c++, vector, pass-by-reference, member-functions

I tried searching a lot but I couldn't find an answer. Almost every answer I found is about passing between two classes.

My problem is that I want to declare and define a vector of strings in one member function, then I want another member function of the same class to modify said vector, and it's just not working out.  Here is my code:

```
void Game::draw_table(){

std::vector<std::string> L(3);

L[0] = "something";
L[1] = "something else";
L[2] = "yet another something";

std::cout << L[0] << std::endl;
std::cout << L[1] << std::endl;
std::cout << L[2] << std::endl;
}
```

and then I want this other member function to modify it:

```
void Game::play_game(){

//some code

if (coord1 == 1 && coord2 == 1)
    L[0] = "new something";
}
```

A friend told me that since they're in the same class I shouldn't need to do anything but it keeps saying "Undeclared identifier L".

Comment: I think this is C++, so I have retagged it.

Comment: one capital letter names are terrible for variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have two solutions you can declare your vector as a member variable

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Game
{
    std::vector<std::string> _l;

    public:
        Game();
        ~Game();

    void draw();
 };
```

or you can also just directly give as parameter to your function

but the member variable declaration seems to be the best solution

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have declared a local variable in a member function and expected it to be visible from another member function.

If you want a variable to be available across member functions, you must declare it as a [member variable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members) of the class, inside the class declaration, and not declare it as a local variable to the function.